# JBPM Use Database Instead of .bpmn file

Tags: jbpm

I wonder if I could use database instead of traditional .bpmn files used to describe processes? I mean can I define my processes and state transitions to the database instead of files?

Comment: I'm newbi in jBPM...so far, just setting up a project and running a simple process through a ".bpmn" file. Now I want to move this process to database, so I can change it at runtime

Answer (score 0):

As I read some articles, it seems be possible to store jbpm process definitions in database instead of bmpn xml files, but what about in the latest version? I wonder if it's still possible?

[if it's possible to Store Process Definition in Database](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201479)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using bpmn2 files is to have an interchangeable format so you are not tied to any particular tool. This might sound as not needed when you begin, but after a couple of years you will understand why this is a must. You can obviously store the xml file in a database, that will be inefficient though. The state and transitions of the process instances are indeed stored in the database by default in jbpm, but they are using a binary format for performance reasons. The question is what benefits do you see in storing the process file and the state in the db?